# how to set default value in multiple select dropdown list angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having a multiselect dropdown as below

```
<select id="year" multiple ng-model="type"  ng-disabled="!type1" >
    <option value="all" selected>all</option>
    <option value='2012'>2012</option>
    <option value='2013'>2013</option>
    <option value='2014'>2014</option>
    <option value='2015'>2015</option>
    <option value='2016'>2016</option>
    <option value='2017'>2017</option>
    <option value='2018'>2018</option>
    <option value='2019'>2019</option>
</select>
```

I want to set option "all" as a default value. For that I wrote "selected" keyword inside the option tag, which I want to appear by default in my drop down list as you can see in the above code. But it is not working . Can anyone please help me how can i set the default value.

Comment: Take a look at ngOptions https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions to use the angular way.

Comment: Can you post your controller code too?

Comment: Could you check if [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42396482/4927984) solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default in your controller. Remember that the value of a multiselect is an array so you'll have to set `$scope.type` to an array. Here is a working example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.type = ["all"];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select id="year" multiple ng-model="type">
      <option value="all" selected>all</option>
      <option value='2012'>2012</option>
      <option value='2013'>2013</option>
      <option value='2014'>2014</option>
      <option value='2015'>2015</option>
      <option value='2016'>2016</option>
      <option value='2017'>2017</option>
      <option value='2018'>2018</option>
      <option value='2019'>2019</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    {{type}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Angular way would be to use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```
<select ng-model="type" ng-options="o for o in options"/>
```

Where options is an array set in your controller:

```
$scope.options = [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, ...];
```

---

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.options = [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-options="o for o in options" ng-model="type">
    <option value="">all</option>
  </select>
  <br>selected: {{type}}
</div>
```